# How to rotate libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to rotate a sprite in an android app using LibGDX. I have used sprite.rotate and sprite.setRotation in an attempt to rotate the sprite, but none have worked.

```
public Cannon(){
    cannend = new Texture("cannonend.png");
    cannon = new Sprite(cannend, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2) + 3, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6), (cannend.getWidth()), (cannend.getHeight()));
    cannon.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2) + 3, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6));
    cannon.setRotation(70);
    cannon.setCenter((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2));
}
```

When I draw this sprite in my Playstate class this is the code that I use.

```
 public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cannon = new Cannon();
    cannontop = new Texture("Cannon.png");
    man = new Man(0, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 4));
    bg = new Texture("background.png");
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 2160, 3840);
}
```

//skipped some irrelevant code

```
 @Override
 public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
    sb.draw(man.getTexture(), man.getPosition().x, man.getPosition().y);
    sb.draw(cannontop, (bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannon.getTextureWidth() / 2) - 23, (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5));
    sb.draw(cannon.getTexture(), (bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannon.getTextureWidth() / 2), (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5) - (cannontop.getWidth() / 2) + 8);
    sb.end();
}
```

I have just learnt Java, so please forgive me if some of my code is bad. I have also added and taken away single pixels for the widths and heights when drawing things - I'm not sure whether this is ok, as I normally use ratios because they dont seem to affect gameplay when screen sizes change. Anyway, what could I use to rotate the sprite a certain amount every frame? Also, what does sprite.getX() do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not drawing sprite you are drawing texture of sprite.

```
sprite.draw(batch);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. How would I create a batch with the information for my cannon in my Playstate class? Thanks.

Comment: its just a regular spritebatch you dont need any specific batch.
Edit: Dont use spritebatch as a parameter in render. 
Look here for proper game structure.
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/02/LibGDX-Tutorial-3-Basic-graphics.aspx